# grep specific files and copy those specific files

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

these are my files and which is output of `ll | awk '{print $9}'`

```
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:00:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:05:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:10:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:15:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:20:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:25:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:30:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:35:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:40:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:45:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:50:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_10:55:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:00:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:05:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:10:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:15:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:20:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:25:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:30:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:35:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:40:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:45:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:50:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_11:55:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:00:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:05:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:10:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:15:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:20:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:25:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:30:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:35:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:40:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:45:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:50:01*
thread_dump_10-10-22_12:55:01*
```

My question is copy the files between 11:30 to 12:30 to some folder. Source: `/home/Downloads/thread_dumps` and destination: `/home/test`

Comment: I've formatted the code in your question for you. What are the asterisks (`*`) on the end of each filename? If they aren't really part of the filename please [edit] your question to remove them all

Comment: Do you want to include the 12:30 file in the set of copies?

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` command and assuming that all the files follow the same pattern (with the hour at the end):

```bash
find /home/Downloads/thread_dumps \( -name  '*11:[3-5][0-9]:*' -o -name '*12:[0-2][0-9]:*' -o -name '*12:30:[0-5][0-9]*' \) -exec cp --target-directory=/home/test {} +
```

The command above will copy the files that have `12:30:??` (if the time is 12:31 or more then the file will not be considered)

If you don't want files with `12:30` then you should this `find` command:

```bash
find /home/Downloads/thread_dumps \( -name  '*11:[3-5][0-9]:*' -o -name '*12:[0-2][0-9]:*' \) -exec cp --target-directory=/home/test {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell glob to achieve what you want, without having to rely on other commands like `grep` or `find`. This includes the file with the 12:30 timestamp:

```
cp /home/Downloads/thread_dumps/thread_dump_10-10-22_11:[345]* \
   /home/Downloads/thread_dumps/thread_dump_10-10-22_12:[012]* \
   /home/Downloads/thread_dumps/thread_dump_10-10-22_12:30* \
   /home/test
```

Note that the final `*` here is a *wildcard* and not related to the trailing `*` that your files seems to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the files, matching them will a shell glob:

```
cp /home/Downloads/thread_dumps/thread_dump_10-10-22_11:[345]?:?? /home/test
cp /home/Downloads/thread_dumps/thread_dump_10-10-22_12:[12]?:?? /home/test
cp /home/Downloads/thread_dumps/thread_dump_10-10-22_12:30:00 /home/test
```

I've put these out as three commands but you could put all three source patterns into the same `cp` command if you wanted, either literally as three separate arguments or combined using the `{x,y,z}` brace expansion like I've done here:

```
# Assuming `bash` or `ksh`
cp /home/Downloads/thread_dumps/thread_dump_10-10-22_{11:[345]?:??,12:[12]?:??,12:30:00} /home/test
```

Omit the third command (or pattern) if you don't want to include the 12:30 file.

The `[...]` component matches to any one of the enclosed characters. The `?` matches any single character. (The one you may be most familiar with is `*`, which matches any number of zero or more characters.)

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
cp thread_dump_10-10-22_??:??:??(e['
  [[ $REPLY[-8,-1] > 11:30 && REPLY[-8,-1] < 12:31 ]]']) /home/test
```

That's using the `e` glob qualifier to select files based on the result of the `e`valuation of some code (where the file to consider is in the `$REPLY` variable). Here doing string comparison of the last 8 characters of the file name selecting files ending in 11:30:00 to 12:30:59.